# What's the next year of 2011-02-28?

Tags: java

It's obvious that the next year of 2011-01-01 is 2012-01-01 and the next year of 2011-03-01 is 2012-03-01.

But, what's the next year of 2011-02-28? 2012-02-28 or 2012-02-29?

Likes, I keep the shares one year from 2011-02-28, what's the end date?

In java, I know that the previous year of 2012-02-29 ( Calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1) ) is 2011-02-28. However, the next year of 2011-02-28 is 2012-02-28.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: You need to ask the users of the application what they would want "next year" to mean in this case.

Comment: it will prolly just an error or something, test it yourself. Or google a bit to see what happens to leapyears

Answer (score 2):

I think that depends on your business rules. To me one year from Feb 28 is always Feb 28 of the next year. You bought your shares on a specific date, not on some rule that it is the last day of the month. If you bought your shares on the 27th, then one from then is the 27th. Etc. etc.

But your business is free to define that differently. I don't think this is really a programming question at all, but a business logic question.

Comment: The problem is indeed in 29th. I think the most obvious thing is handle this exception so if it´s 29 one year after should be 1st of March